# Do I need SMTP or other any CNAME records after adding G Suite MX records?

Tags: dns, email, cname, mx, smtp

I'm setting up G Suite and I'm adding its `MX records` to my DNS settings.

Here are my current DNS records (default from my host provider):

[image]

I will delete the `MX 10` record and add the ones from G Suite, right?

But should I delete any of `CNAME` records? Liek `SMTP`, or `mail`, or `webmail`? There are from my host provider, when I first registered the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to delete those.  They are aliases i.e. if someone uses `smtp.example.com` or any of those others, then that URL resolves to `example.com`.   For example, if you were using IMAP or SMTP to mail hosted on your own server the you might have `mail.example.com` as the host.  But you don't need that any longer.

If you have changed your MX records to GSuite then these DNS records simply won't work, but it is unlikely they are going to be used so it is no drama to delete them or leave them.